# Filling in matrix with unique matches between two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, match, lapply

First I have a dataframe of GO terms and associated genes (go.d5g):

```
          ID    Gene                             Term
1 GO:0001922    ABL1           B-1 B cell homeostasis
2 GO:0001922   HIF1A           B-1 B cell homeostasis
3 GO:0001922 TNFAIP3           B-1 B cell homeostasis
4 GO:0001922   SH2B2           B-1 B cell homeostasis
5 GO:0002901     ADA  mature B cell apoptotic process
6 GO:0001777     BAX T cell homeostatic proliferation
```

Then I have a dataframe of differentially expressed genes from various experimental comparisons (deg):

```
       L2FC    Gene       diffexp           comp
1 -2.754236 SLC13A2 Downregulated NS.CB.A,S.ED.A
2  3.161623   SNAI2   Upregulated NS.CB.A,S.ED.A
3 -2.821350   STYK1 Downregulated NS.CB.A,S.ED.A
4 -1.798022    CD84 Downregulated NS.CB.A,S.ED.A
5 -1.293536    TLE6 Downregulated NS.CB.A,S.ED.A
6 -1.011016   P2RX1 Downregulated NS.CB.A,S.ED.A
```

I want a matrix with 0/1 for matches between unique values in deg$Gene and go.d5g$ID.  Here's a fake example:

```
        GO:0001922 GO:0002901 GO:0001777 GO:0006924 GO:0033153 GO:0002204
SLC13A2          1          1          0          0          0          0
SNAI2            0          0          0          0          0          0
STYK1            0          1          1          0          1          0
CD84             0          0          0          0          0          0
TLE6             0          1          1          0          0          0
P2RX1            0          0          0          0          0          1
```

So the rows of the matrix are unique genes in the experimental set, while the columns are unique IDs from the GO database.

How do I fill this in with (1)s for matching genes?  I currently have something very crude like this:

```
g.u <- unique(deg$Gene)
goid.u <- unique(go.d5g$ID)
cmat <- matrix(0,nrow=length(g.u),ncol=length(goid.u))
rownames(cmat) <- g.u
colnames(cmat) <- goid.u

for (i in 1:length(g.u)) {
  go.match <- unlist(lapply(g.u[i], function(x) which(go.d5g$Gene %in% x)))
  go.match2 <- go.d5g$ID[go.match]
  cmat[i,which(goid.u %in% go.match2)] <- 1
}
```

After a bunch of fixing issues I think it's working the crude way, but maybe a better solution is out there.

```
sum(cmat)
[1] 1457

cmat.o <- cmat[order(rowSums(cmat),decreasing=T),order(colSums(cmat),decreasing=T)]

cmat.o[1:10,1:5]
      GO:0006355 GO:0043066 GO:0006468 GO:0043065 GO:0006338
TNF            0          0          0          1          0
SOX9           0          1          1          0          1
ABL1           1          0          1          1          0
IL10           0          1          0          0          0
KIT            0          0          0          0          0
IL1B           0          0          0          0          0
CCL3           0          0          0          0          0
THBS1          0          1          0          0          0
ROCK2          0          0          1          0          0
FLNA           0          1          0          0          0
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are the column names of `deg`?

Comment: @LMc   Ah, they accidentally got cut off.  I fixed the post.

Comment: You say you want the rows to be unique genes from `deg`, but all the rows you show are from `go.d5g`

Comment: Also, `IEA25` is a `Gene` that exists for `GO:0001922` in your `go.d5g` data frame, but does it also exist for `GO:0001777`? If it does not exist what you you expect in the output? If it does exist and it has a match in `deg` then which combination of `Gene` and `ID` would get a 1 for this match?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Based on your comments:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

full_join(go.d5g, deg, by = "Gene") |>
  mutate(matched = as.numeric(!is.na(ID))) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Gene, names_from = ID, values_from = matched, values_fill = 0L) |>
  filter(Gene %in% deg$Gene) |>
  select(-any_of("NA"))
```

Here you merge to find the matches and then pivot the data. Lastly, you only keep Genes that are in `deg$Gene`.

---

**Previous Response**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

go.d5g |>
  mutate(in_deg = as.numeric(Gene %in% deg$Gene)) |>
  select(ID, in_deg, Gene) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = in_deg, values_fill = 0L)
```

If you need `Gene` as row names instead of a column just add `tibble::column_to_rownames("Gene")` to the pipeline.

**Output**

```
  Gene     `GO:0001922` `GO:0002901` `GO:0001777`
  <chr>           <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 IEA25               0            0            0
2 IEA3091             0            0            0
3 ISS7128             0            0            0
4 IEA10603            0            0            0
5 IEA100              0            0            0
6 IEA581              0            0            0
```

**Data**

```
go.d5g <- structure(list(ID = c("GO:0001922", "GO:0001922", "GO:0001922", 
"GO:0001922", "GO:0002901", "GO:0001777"), Gene = c("IEA25", 
"IEA3091", "ISS7128", "IEA10603", "IEA100", "IEA581"), Term = c("B-1 B cell homeostasis", 
"B-1 B cell homeostasis", "B-1 B cell homeostasis", "B-1 B cell homeostasis", 
"mature B cell apoptotic process", "T cell homeostatic proliferation"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

deg <- structure(list(L2FC = c(-2.754236, 3.161623, -2.82135, -1.798022, 
-1.293536, -1.011016), Gene = c("SLC13A2", "SNAI2", "STYK1", 
"CD84", "TLE6", "P2RX1"), diffexp = c("Downregulated", "Upregulated", 
"Downregulated", "Downregulated", "Downregulated", "Downregulated"
), comp = c("NS.CB.A,S.ED.A", "NS.CB.A,S.ED.A", "NS.CB.A,S.ED.A", 
"NS.CB.A,S.ED.A", "NS.CB.A,S.ED.A", "NS.CB.A,S.ED.A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: This format seems to be good, but for some reason the return is all (0)s.  To answer your earlier questions, the go.d5g set is a list of GO terms with related genes, with plenty of overlap (genes show up under multiple GO:#).  Total 41032 genes tied to 3712 GO terms.  I see now I made a mistake but the rows should be unique from deg$Gene, totaling 626.  I'm thinking I could also drop the 0 columns and rows later.

Comment: In the example data you provide there are no genes in `go.d5g` that are also in `deg`.

Comment: There are matches in the full dataset, I just don't know how to include that here given the sheer size.  I'm adding another example in the original post.

Comment: It would be helpful to add a few rows to your input data frames so there is a match and then update your expected output.

Comment: @threadofmotion updated my response based on your comments.